# Obtaining text from span in Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

I'm having trouble obtaining a list of text using selenium 2.46.0. I want to return each text value in the spans.

The HTML code:

```
<p id="wordList">
  <span>
      owl
  </span>
  <span>
      end
  </span>
</p>
```

Notice that the span tags do not have a class or id to reference.

My code:

```
List<WebElement> spans = driver.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
    for (WebElement span : spans) {
        System.out.println(span.getText());
    }
```

It doesn't return any text whatsoever. In fact, it doesn't even recognize that the span tags exist. I have also tried different variations (XPath, CSSSelector, etc...) but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you positive that the webdriver instance has loaded the page in question?

Comment: Is the given HTML really all that is loaded by the webdriver? No JavaScript or CSS on that page? Both can influence webdriver in a way that could explain your findings.

Comment: Yes the page gets loaded. I have tried using the different unit drivers and the page does load.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to find the spans from the parent node using the following css

```
#wordList>span
```

Implementation:

```
List<WebElement> spans = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#wordList>span"));
for (WebElement span : spans) {
     System.out.println(span.getText());
}
```

Using tagName and *span* is not very feasible to locate the element from a web page since that can contain a lot of them.

Comment: Your code works, but only when using FirefoxDriver. HtmlUnitDriver returns no results...Thank you though!